# async method when passed as parameter of Func<T> placeholder in a Wrapper method I get compile error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a wrapper method

```
public static T WebMethodWrapper<T>(this ApplicationService applicationService, Func<T> webMethod)
{
   //Do Something...
}
```

I want to use this service method to wrap the web method call like below. When tried to use this I get compile error saying "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomeMethodAsync(int param1, int param2, List<int> param3)
        {
            return new WebMethodWrapper(
                async Task<bool>() => DoSomeWorkMethodAsync(param1, param2, param3)

            );
        }

private async Task<bool> DoSomeWorkMethodAsync(int param1, int param2, List<int> param3)
{
    //Do Some Logic
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your method signature says that `Task<bool>` but you are returning a `new WebMethodWrapper`. In the first place why would you want to do that?

Comment: Your method is an ``extension method`` for ``ApplicationService``. if you want to use as a normal method you should pass applicationService for first parameter and second parameter is your Func

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü  I have a UI ajax call to DoSomeMethodAsync() and this should return a bool. I have a private method DoSomeWorkMethodAsync() which returns Task<bool>. The WebMethodWraper is a extension method which provides some application level logging and few other functionalities. How can I bridge these?

Comment: If WebMethodWrapper is an extension how can you do `new WebMethodWrapper `

Comment: you need to show us more code. It is really hard to guess right now